# Qt signal and slot doesn't work when QTableView is updated

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have a `QTableView` and a button. I have used signal and slot to connect table view with a function. The slot performs following function. Whenever user selects single row the button must be enabled.  If user doesn't select a row or if more than one row is selected, then the button must be disabled. This is the code.

```
connect(ui->client_table->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, constQItemSelection &)),SLOT(disableButtons(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)));
```

The problem starts when i refresh the table view. Then the signal and slot stops working. The code to refresh the table is given below.

```
void client_table_view::refreshTable()
{



    dbconnector db;
    QSqlQueryModel* modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
    QSqlQuery* qry = new QSqlQuery(db.digi_db);


    qry->exec("select client_id,company_name,contact_name,address,email,phone from client_details");

    int qrycount = 0;


    modal->setQuery(*qry);
    ui->client_table->setModel(modal);
}
```

How can i change the code so that i can refresh the table along with implementing the signal and slot mechanism.

Comment: Per the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setModel). "Sets the model for the view to present.

This function will create and set a new selection model, replacing any model that was previously set with setSelectionModel(). However, the old selection model will not be deleted as it may be shared between several views. We recommend that you delete the old selection model if it is no longer required." -- The signall/slot connection stops working becuase the selection model is replaced.

Comment: Calling [`QSqlQueryModel::setQuery`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery) will reset the model. You don't have to create a new model every time you execute a query. Also, don't initialize objects with `new` unless you need them to survive beyond the current scope. For example you can initialize `QSqlQuery` with just `QSqlQuery query("...", db.digidb);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the start of refresh() to tidy up:

```
disconnect(ui->client_table->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, constQItemSelection &)),SLOT(disableButtons(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)));
```

And then use this to connect with you new model at the end of refresh():

```
connect(ui->client_table->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, constQItemSelection &)),SLOT(disableButtons(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)));
```

Comment: Why not just create and set the model once instead of each time the refresh is performed. This also doesn't address the memory leak.

Comment: @JamesAdkison The question was about the signal not working - I have only posted a fix for that. Also the OP "may" have a tidy function elsewhere to deal with the memory allocation - can't really tell since we don't have the whole code.